# returning dictionary of generator the most efficient way

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools, robustness

I have written this function that returns a `dictionary`, I think either by `itertools` or by just using `yeild` i can return `dictionary` but I have never done that in case of a `dictionary`

```
def configDb():
    """ Reads git global config file

        Returns:
            config(dict): git config settings
    """
    # Read git config file
    configFile, _ = execGitCommand('git config --list')
    config = {}
    for line in (each for each in configFile.split("\n") if each):
        config[line.split("=")[0]] = line.split("=")[-1]

    return config
```

how can I make this function act in a way I do not have to call like `configDb()` but instead just `configDb[key]` should give me value ?

Comment: What is the point of a "dictionary generator"? The dictionary is not useful until all items are loaded; just return a dict.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries can't be `generator`ed, but you can `yield` **key-value** tuples

```
def configDb():
    """ Reads git global config file

        Returns:
            config(dict): git config settings
    """
    # Read git config file
    configFile, _ = execGitCommand('git config --list')
    config = {}
    for line in (each for each in configFile.split("\n") if each):
        yield line.split("=")[0], line.split("=")[-1]
```

Comment: I think i would have to stick to my current implementation.

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't blame you :)

Answer (score 0):

A partial config file is hardly useful, so there doesn't seem to be much point in a "generated dictionary".

```
def configDb():
    """ Reads git global config file

        Returns:
            config(dict): git config settings
    """
    # Read git config file
    configFile, _ = execGitCommand('git config --list')
    rows = (line.split("=") for line in configFile.splitlines())
    return dict(row for row in rows if len(row)==2)
```